# pass boolean type js variable value from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass a boolean type JAVASCRIPT variable value from one html page to another (from page1.html to  page2.html). I am not getting idea to do this. I am not sure whether my approach is right or wrong. *Please suggest me the correct way to do this.*

the value of **first_load** should change when the page loads for the first time and the changed value is to be sent to another html page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      first_load = false; 
      function load() {
        first_load = true;
        alert("first_load="+first_load);
        //pass the value of first_load to page2.html
      }
    </script>
  </head>    
  <body onload="load()">    
  </body>
</html>
```

**how can I get the value of first_load at page2.html??**

Comment: I *think* you mis-understood AJAX, basically it's to pass variables to server-side script, like PHP, get it's response and display it dynamically

Comment: Yea what exactly are you doing it for?

Comment: Fixed indenting. There's an extra `}` floating around — just saying.

Comment: @ alvin wong thanks for the reply. okie then how to pass the value from page1.html to page2.html. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @sam really still don't understand, are you trying to navigate to `page2.html`, and at the same time store a value so that `page2.html` can retrieve it? (and the way you reply comment is wrong [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting))

Comment: @alvin thanks for the suggestion and as for your query I just want to pass the value of first_load to another page i.e.page2.html but not to load the page page2.html.

Comment: @sam unless you are running a server-side script, I don't think it is useful without loading `page2.html`. Perhaps you need to write **more clearly** about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you trying to do you can use

html5 webstorage

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

cookies

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

or you can use just a qurystring after all a bool value is just true or false

Comment: can I use **html5 webstorage** because I am creating simple webpage without using html5?

Comment: @sam yes you can it the job of browser to recognize the html5 in your JavaScript and I think most of the current browser support web storage I also think it the most straight forward approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through url variables, cookies, or HTML5 Web Storage.

Url Variables:

[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Cookies

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

HTML5 Web Storage

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

The most transparent to the user and my choice would be cookies.